# How to ensure a script generates custom usernames based on employee names and alerts on conflicts

Tags: powershell, active-directory, collision-detection

Right now I have a code to create users in a domain. You pass 3 variables and it creates the account. It can create accounts just fine.

Since we employ hundreds of people, it also needs to be able to handle new accounts that might end up with the same generated name as an already existing one.

What I would want is to have it see that the currently generated username is an existing account already, and offer a prompt to enter in a custom username instead, and then go forward with the creation. As of right now, if I run the code and there's a collision, the code just won't run with error.

```
"New-ADUser : The operation failed because UPN value provided for addition/modification is not unique forest-wide"
```

What I have so far is:

```
param($firstname, $lastname, $location)
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$username = ($firstname.Substring(0,1) + $lastname).ToLower()

$userExists = Get-ADUser -Filter {sAMAccountName -eq $username}
if ($userExists -ne $null) {
    Write-Host "The username '$username' already exists in Active Directory. Please enter a custom username:"
    $customUsername = Read-Host
    $username = $customUsername
}


$path = "OU=Users,OU=$location,OU=GS,DC=domain,DC=com"

New-ADUser `
    -Name "$firstname $lastname" `
    -GivenName $firstname `
    -Surname $lastname `
    -UserPrincipalName "$username@domain.com" `
    -SamAccountName $username `
    -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "Password123" -AsPlainText -Force) `
    -Path $path `
    -ProfilePath "\\domain\homes\profiles\$username" `
    -ChangePasswordAtLogon 1 `
    -Enabled 1 `
    -OtherAttributes @{'gidNumber'='711132'; 'uid'= '$username'} `

Add-ADGroupMember `
    -Identity "$location" -Members $username

$user = Get-ADUser -Identity $username
$sid = $user.SID
$last4DigitsOfObjectSid = $sid.Value.Substring($sid.Value.Length - 4)
$newUidNumber = "71$last4DigitsOfObjectSid"
Set-ADUser -Identity $username -Replace @{'uidNumber'=$newUidNumber}
```

Comment: You can put `New-ADUser` in a try/catch block and put the new username prompt in the catch section.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop where you test if the username is already taken before proceeding with the creation of a new user.

Also, I would recommend using [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) to keep all userparameters in a clean structure without having to use those nasty backticks (or a very, very long line of code)

And if you also specify switch `PassThru` the New-ADUser cmdlet will return the newly created user object straight away, so you can omit the extra Get-ADUser call.

```
param($firstname, $lastname, $location)
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$path     = "OU=Users,OU=$location,OU=GS,DC=domain,DC=com"
$username = ($firstname.Substring(0,1) + $lastname).ToLower()

# test if the username (=SamAccountName) is unique
while ((Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$username'")) {
    Write-Warning "The username '$username' already exists in Active Directory."
    $username = Read-Host "Please enter a new custom username. Leave empty to quit."
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($username)) { exit }
}

# create a splatting Hashtable for the parameters of New-ADUser
$userParams = @{
    Name                  = "$firstname $lastname"
    GivenName             = $firstname
    Surname               = $lastname
    UserPrincipalName     = "$username@domain.com"
    SamAccountName        = $username
    # always use single quotes around a hardcoded password to avoid string interpolation
    AccountPassword       = (ConvertTo-SecureString 'Password123' -AsPlainText -Force)
    Path                  = $path
    ProfilePath           = "\\domain\homes\profiles\$username"
    ChangePasswordAtLogon = $true
    Enabled               = $true
    OtherAttributes       = @{'gidNumber'='711132'; 'uid'= $username}
    # have New-ADUser return the user object
    PassThru              = $true
}

$user = New-ADUser @userParams
# calculate the UidNumber from the users SID
$last4DigitsOfObjectSid = $user.SID -replace '.*(\d{4})$', '$1'
$newUidNumber = "71$last4DigitsOfObjectSid"
Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Replace @{'uidNumber'=$newUidNumber}

# and add the new user to the group
# here $location is both the name of a group AND the name for the OU
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $location -Members $user
```